# Control Center is not accessible outside of VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I am trying to setup a Kafka Conflient on VM and have followed all steps here - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html.

But in my case `http://<hostname>:9021` is not getting accessible.

Answer (score 1):

The VM hostname wouldn't be resolvable from outside of the VM

You need to port forward (refer to the documentation for the specific VM tool you use) from the VM to the host and access `http://localhost:9021`

As far as installation goes, you can look at a repo I created for setting up [Confluent Platform in Vagrant](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/cp-ansible-vagrant)
with their Ansible repository (you'll need to change some files if you only want Control Center)